# Calculate energy from an reaction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, nuclear-physics, radioactivity

I'm trying to calculate the *released energy from a reaction*. 
The radioactive substance polonium decays according to this formula:
$$^{210}_{84}\mbox{Po} \rightarrow \mbox{X}+^4_{2}\mbox{He} $$
At first I solved X to be: $^{206}_{82} \mbox{Pb}$

Now when I have the whole reaction, what formula should I use?

Comment: Someone could please edit the question and write the formulas, I couldn't

Comment: Do you expect us to visit unknown, quite possibly malware-infected sites and do your work for you? Try harder.

Comment: have you thought of energy conservation given the special relativity relation of mass with energy?

Comment: @DeerHunter and the other downvoter: why such hostility to a new user? You could ignore the question after all. kudos to Nivalth for taking the risk you perceived in the link.

Comment: Sorry for the links, but cheers for that Nivalth edited it!

Comment: Found a way! I will answer my question soon when I can

Comment: @annav - I could ignore the question but not the risk it may be posing to the unwary. To the OP and others: please do not use abbreviated links. There is enough space in the question.

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please see [our homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/715/7433). We expect homework and homework-like problems to have some effort put into them, and deal with conceptual issues. If you edit your question to explain (1) What you have tried, (2) the concept you have trouble with, and (3) your level of understanding, I'll be happy to reopen this. (Flag this message for ♦ attention with a custom message, or reply to me in the comments with `@Manishearth` to notify me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [mass of the original polonium atom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopes_of_polonium#Table) is 209.9828737(13)AU, while the [mass of the lead atom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopes_of_lead#Table) is 205.9744653(13)AU and the [mass of the helium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopes_of_helium#Table) is 4.00260325415(6)AU. The [mass deficit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binding_energy#Mass_change) gives you the amount of energy released.